# How can I determine if a subroutine is being called inside eval using caller?

Tags: perl

I'm still learning Perl and I was tasked to use `caller` to determine if a subroutine is being called from an `eval` at any higher level. I am supposed to come up with some code to test this on and print `Yes` if its from an `eval` or `No` if its not. I cannot find any good examples on how to use `caller` on the web and was wondering if anyone had any ideas or suggestions on how to go about doing this.

Comment: Did you begin by looking at the [perldoc `caller` reference page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html)?  In particular, it appears that this function would be called inside a function of interest; the `(eval)` marker would only show up in `caller(1)[3]` (or perhaps `caller(0)[3]`) if this function of interest has been `eval`'d...

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using caller for this. Refer to [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
$EXCEPTIONS_BEING_CAUGHT
$^S
Current state of the interpreter.

    $^S         State
    ---------   -------------------------------------
    undef       Parsing module, eval, or main program
    true (1)    Executing an eval
    false (0)   Otherwise

The first state may happen in $SIG{__DIE__} and $SIG{__WARN__} handlers.
The English name $EXCEPTIONS_BEING_CAUGHT is slightly misleading, because the
undef value does not indicate whether exceptions are being caught, since 
compilation of the main program does not catch exceptions.

This variable was added in Perl 5.004.
```

As to why:

```
C:\Users\user>perl -MBenchmark -E "timethese(20000000, {'caller' => sub {caller()}, '$^S' => sub {$^S}})"
Benchmark: timing 20000000 iterations of $^S, caller...
       $^S:  0 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.11 CPU) @ 183486238.53/s (n=20000000)
            (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
    caller:  1 wallclock secs ( 0.87 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.87 CPU) @ 22909507.45/s (n=20000000)
```

And this is before we even bog the caller code down with a number of iterations over the call stack and running string functions against stack levels, assuming we'll write bug-free code for all edge cases, etc.

Writing code to use caller to determine this is a complete re implementation of a core feature. It's like asking, "How do I use scalars to implement a linked list?" The answer should be "Use an array", not "Here's how!"

Comment: I'm confused how this answers the question...  The OP was "tasked to use `caller` ..." to determine the specified information.  Do you have an example of how this variable would be successfully used in a script?

Comment: @abiessu I was going to make a similar comment, but this answer will certainly be useful to future visitors, even if it is outside the scope of the OP's assignment (I assume homework).

Comment: I see your point; perhaps you could expound a bit on why `caller` is less desirable to use compared with `$^S`?  All I can see so far is that `caller` has lots of useful info and `$^S` may or may not tell me what I want to know...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I agree, but now I am curious as to whether there is an interesting reason that `$^S` is better than `caller` in general...

Comment: @abiessu For one, `$^S` is easier to use because there's no need to iterate through the call stack.

Comment: Why would you want to get the call stack and iterate over it running string comparison functions when you can just grab the current state of $^S?

Comment: `perl -MEnglish -E "sub in_eval { if ($EXCEPTIONS_BEING_CAUGHT) { say 'Yes' } else { say 'No' } } in_eval(); eval { in_eval(); }; eval 'in_eval()'; in_eval();"` - and the example

Comment: One problem with `$^S`: `local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { ... $^S ... }; eval 'use ModuleWithSyntaxError;'` won't show you're in an `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

With the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

eval "test_eval();";

test_eval();

sub test_eval {
  my ($e,$v,$a,$l,) = caller(0);

  print "[$e], [$v], [$a], [$l]\n";
}
```

I get output

```
[main], [(eval 1)], [1], [main::test_eval]
[main], [test.pl], [21], [main::test_eval]
```

But if I change it to use `caller(1)` then I get

```
[main], [test.pl], [19], [(eval)]
[], [], [], []
```

and several warnings about uninitialized values.

This should give you a starting point to work from.  Note that the values in the array after index 3 have been ignored in this program as they do not appear to relate to the problem at hand, but refer back to [the `caller` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) to find out if any of those values would be useful.

Edit:

Given the discussion on and the content of another answer, you could supply a cheeky solution like this:

```
sub func_under_eval {
  if (0) { # change this to 1 when the time is right
    return (defined($^S) and $^S>0)?"Yes":"No";
  }
  else {
    my @calls = caller(0);
    my $back = 1;
    while (defined($caller[0])) {
      if (index("(eval", $caller[1] . $caller[3])>-1)
        return "Yes";
      @calls = caller($back++);
    }
    return "No";
  }
}
```