# Can you tell when your code is inside eval block?

Tags: perl, eval, subroutine

Is there a way for my code (a method in a Perl library) to tell if it is executed from within an `eval {}` block?

What I'd like to have is something like:

```
sub mySub {
    my $isInEval = isInEval();
    if ($isInEval) {
        # Do a dying thing
    } else {
        # Do a non-dying thing.
    }
}
```

*For issues related to rollout complexity, there's no way for me to collapse dying and non-dying code into the same identical block of code that wouldn't care if we are inside eval or not.*

Comment: Self-answering since I just figured the asnwer out while researching the question

Comment: Just curious -- why would you care if you're in eval? Shouldn't you always `die` or `croak` and let the caller handle whatever you cannot handle?

Comment: @Robert - long and sad deployment story that I have no control over.

Comment: this is really horrible action at a distance and should be avoided if at all possible

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out. [`perldoc caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) says:

```
# 0 1 2 3 4
($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs,
# 5 6 7 8 9 10
$wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash)
= caller($i);
```

> Note that $subroutine may be (eval) if the frame is not a subroutine call, but an eval. In such a case additional elements $evaltext and $is_require are set: $is_require is true if the frame is created by a require or use statement, $evaltext contains the text of the eval EXPR statement. In particular, for an eval BLOCK statement, $subroutine is (eval) , but $evaltext is undefined.

I tested this by using

> perl -e 'use Data::Dumper;sub x { foreach my $i (0..5) { my @c=caller($i);print Data::Dumper->Dump([\@c])} }; sub y1 { x()}; sub z { eval{y1()} }; sub z2{z();}; z2()'

And indeed, call #4 had `caller[3]` output as

```
$VAR1 = [
      'main',
      '-e',
      1,
      '(eval)',
      0,
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      0,
      ''
    ];
```

---

Final code:

```
 sub isInEval{ 
     my $i=0; 
     while(1) {
        my ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs
           ,$wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash)
            = caller($i); 
        last unless defined $package; 
        $i++; 
        if ($subroutine eq "(eval)" || $evaltext) { 
            return 1;
        } 
    }; 
    return 0; 
}
sub x {
    if (isInEval()) {
        print "eval\n";
    } else {
        print "NO eval\n";
    }
}
sub y1 { x() }; 
sub z1 { eval{y1()} }; 
sub w1 { z1(); }; 
print "w1: eval expected: ";
w1();

sub y2 { x() }; 
sub z2 { y2() }; 
sub w2 { z2(); }; 
print "w2: eval UNexpected: ";
w2();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$^S` instead? See [How can I determine if a subroutine is being called inside eval using caller?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22183010) (seems like a dupe, btw)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - hm... missed it somehow on my searches. Since I have the dupehammer, closing it myself as a dupe